# Active running javascripts in browser window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Is there a browser addon or extension that would show what javascripts are being run on that window?
For example, if I clicked on a button that activates another javascript then I would like the addon to show that as well.

When "inspect element" in the chrome browser I see the following:

```
<html>
 ....
 <head>
 ....
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        cache: false
                    });

                    Shadowbox.init({
                        skipSetup: true
                    });

                    setInterval(function()
                    {
                        $.get('/download_check.php?fileid=1&session=2', function(data)
                            {
                                if (data.status == 'ok')
                                    window.location = data.dllink;
                            },
                            'json'
                        );
                    }, 30000);

                    if (top.location != self.location)
                        top.location.href = self.location.href;
                });
   </script>
   ...
 </head>
 ... 
</html>
```

So is the setinterval function already running? 
Assuming that I changed the time from 30000 to 3000 from the browser inspection window, would that take effect? Or it does not since the original javascript is already running on the 30000 interval?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use Google chrome JavaScript console shift + ctrl + j on source tab, and debug your js code ,watch expressions, call stack and break points

and there is an extension named Quick Javascript Switcher that turns on/off javascript on the fly : https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher

QJS on the Chrome Webstore : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje

Enjoy !